# Java reflection nested methods not modifying underlying object

Tags: java, pointers, reflection

I am taking in an array of methods and I want to chain them together to modify an object that I am working in.

For example I start with

```
"getStuff().get(1).get(3).setMoreStuff().put(stuff,6)"
```

I split it into an array called methods, and clean up the parameters inside each method and I try to modify this.

```
Object res = this;
String[] methods = targetString.split("\\.(?=\\D)");
for (String m : methods){

    List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();

                    for (String p : m.split("\\(|,|\\)")) {
                        try {
                            if (p.indexOf(".") != -1){
                                double tempD = Double.parseDouble(p);
                                params.add(tempD);
                            } else {
                                int tempP = Integer.parseInt(p);
                                params.add(tempP);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) { //not a number
                            params.add(p);
                        }
                    }
    switch (params.size()) {
        case 1:
            res = res.getClass().getMethod(
                            params.get(0)
                                   ).invoke(res);
            break;
        case 2:
            res = res.getClass().getMethod(
                            params.get(0),
                            params.get(1).getClass()
                                   ).invoke(res, params.get(1));
            break;
        case 3:
            res = res.getClass().getMethod(
                            params.get(0), 
                            params.get(1).getClass(),           
                            params.get(2).getClass()
                                   ).invoke(res, params.get(1), params.get(2));
                                break; 
    }
```

in the end I notice that res has been modified the way that I expect. All the getters and setters are called correctly. But of course the underlying object "this" refers to has not been changed!

I guess I'm just calling the getters and setters of the copy I made in the first line!

now I can't just use

```
this.getClass().getMethod(...).invoke(...)
```

because I need to call the same getMethod on the object returned by this call.

To clarify:

```
Object res = this;
```

creates a "pointer" to this. So that when I call

```
res.getStuff().setStuff(foo)
```

this will also be modified.

but it seem that when I call

```
res = res.getStuff();
res = res.setStuff();
```

like I do in my loop, 
this does not modify the underlying object this refers to?

Edit: Included more code as per request.

Edit2: added anther example, to clarify my problem.

Edit3: tried to add more code, its a bit hard to add a working program without including every class

Comment: It looks like it should be fine to me. You're not actually copying the object at all. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (You may well want to simplify the code a bit, e.g. only call one method, or only support parameterless methods.)

Comment: I added a few more lines of code. But they all seem pretty unrelated. The line that bugs me is inside the switch where I set res = res.getClass().getMethod(...).invoke(...)

Comment: I didn't ask for "a few more lines of code". I asked for a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - something we can run ourselves to help you diagnose the issue. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Sorry @JonSkeet, didn't mean to offend you. Just find it hard to add a full program that will compile and run without all the other classes and infrastructure that is there.

Comment: What's making it hard? It doesn't need "other infrastructure" at all. I'll add an answer which makes it clear what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general approach should be fine (although your approach to parameter conversion is somewhat ugly) - it's the specifics that are presumably causing you problems. Here's a short but complete program demonstrating calling methods and then seeing the difference afterwards:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Person {
    private String name = "default";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // Obviously this would normally take a parameter
    public void setName() {
        name = "name has been set";
    }
}

class Test {

    private Person person = new Person();

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    // Note that we're only declaring throws Exception for convenience
    // here - diagnostic code only, *not* production code!
    public void callMethods(String... methodNames) throws Exception {
        Object res = this;
        for (String methodName : methodNames) {
            Method method = res.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
            res = method.invoke(res);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.callMethods("getPerson", "setName");
        System.out.println(test.getPerson().getName());
    }
}
```

The output is "name has been set" just as I'd expect. So see if you can simplify your code bit by bit, removing extra dependencies etc until you've got something similarly short but complete, but which doesn't work. I suspect you'll actually find the problem as you go.

Comment: Thanks Jon. After a few hours debugging I found that one of the get methods I was calling this way was not really returning the underlying object but returning a copy using the new keyword. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Object does not change reference, its VALUE changes. So if you will call this.get("some key"), you will get value that the same value that you put using reflection.

Right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to say. I am able to call each get and put method for each method in the array. At each step I can see that the variable res is changing but at no point do I have an object that encompasses all the changes that these methods have caused. Are you trying to tell me that everytime I call the assignment operator on res that I am creating a new object?